# Efficient Update SQL, updating multiple rows with one SQL statement, Avoiding Loops

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I'm trying to avoid database access in loops within a project I am working on. Not being too good with SQL, I'm not sure of the best way to approach this.

I'm updating a stock level database in a sale procedure with multiple stock locations/pick locations.

Therefore, this is what I am doing.

Looping through Product IDs, then looping through the pick locations for each product and updating quantities as it goes, like:

```
For Each wProductId In calculatedProds.Keys '' loop through products requested passing values of pick locations
        For i = 0 To locationCount ' split the location value from the string as per above
            Dim thisLocation As Integer = locationID
            Dim thisQty As Integer = qtyPicked                
            Dim sql As String = "UPDATE `stockLevels` SET `stockLevel`=`stockLevel` - '" & thisQty & "' WHERE `stockLocation`='" & thisLocation & "' AND `id`='" & wProductId & "'"
            ' DO DATA ACCESS WITH SQL ABOVE       
        Next
Next
```

Of course this works, but it is opening a new Database Connection for every stock location, for every item.

So how would I work this into a single Update Statement?

http://www.karlrixon.co.uk/writing/update-multiple-rows-with-different-values-and-a-single-sql-query/

That link gets me very close to what I am after, I think, but I am not 100% sure how to dynamically build that SQL statement and how to add two conditions to the CASE.

I need to build a SQL Statement something like:

```
UPDATE stockLevels
SET stockLevel= CASE id
    WHEN '"& wProductId  &"' AND stockLocation='"& thisLocation &"' THEN `stockLevel` - '" & thisQty & "'
    WHEN '"& NEXTwProductId  &"' AND stockLocation='"& NEXTthisLocation &"' THEN `stockLevel` - '" & NEXTthisQty & "'
END
```

But that's not correct where I am adding the second parameter to the CASE!

I am using MySQL and VB.NET, as usual, any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CASE expression is simply incorrect syntactically.

There are two kinds of `CASE` expressions, almost identical to each other and yet slightly different in syntax.

One has the form of

```
CASE expr
  WHEN value1 THEN result1
  WHEN value2 THEN result2
  ...
  ELSE result_else
END
```

The other looks like this:

```
CASE
  WHEN condition1 THEN result1
  WHEN condition2 THEN result2
  ...
  ELSE result_else
END
```

And you were essentially attempting to mix these two kinds of `CASE`.

You probably just need to use the second one (also called *search CASE*, if I am not much mistaken):

```
...
CASE
  WHEN id = '"& wProductId  &"' AND stockLocation='"& thisLocation &"' THEN ...
  WHEN id = '"& NEXTwProductId  &"' AND stockLocation='"& NEXTthisLocation &"' THEN ...
...
```

Note that if there's no match and the `CASE` has no `ELSE` part, the result will be `NULL`, so make sure you've covered all the cases, otherwise use an `ELSE` part like this:

```
ELSE `stocklevel`
```

I.e. the `CASE` will evaluate to the original value of the column being updated, rendering no update for it in the end.

Comment: Oh, I see, so it's literally just a case of not specifying a column name at the start of the `case` statement. Then I can run the `case` with two parameters? That's simple! I knew the syntax I had was wrong, but didn't know how to make it right! Thanks! Comments in the answer from a'r are valid though in that the SQL statement could become very long. In my case we'd probably not be dealing with more than 20 product lines, more than likely fewer than 10 in most instances, do you think using this `case` statement would be the best way to go for this situation?

Comment: In case of no more than 20 lines a CASE solution would seem feasible enough to me. Still, I like the idea by @a'r better in general. You do not seem quite absolutely sure whether you will not be dealing with more product lines in future, so, at the very least, you might want to keep `a'r`'s suggestion in mind (or else consider implementing it at this point).

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to accept this answer as this was what I was looking for originally, but I think @a'r has the better long-term solution. I have never worked with temporary tables though, so am going to shy away from that for now!

Comment: @JamieHartnoll: Well, who am I to oppose the firmness of your hand and the steadfastness of your mind? It's your decision, and I hope the reasons, which you have been so kind to lay out before me, will help me in time to reconcile with the fact of my answer being acceptable enough to become actually accepted. :) Just joking, thanks for the feedback an the explanations. I wonder, though, if, in consistency with the praise you've given to a'r's answer, you could not be prevailed to materialise your praise in as little as upvoting the mentioned answer? :)

Comment: @JamieHartnoll: (To clarify: I'm not related to the author in any way, just thought that if we both commend their answer as the better one, why not make it more obvious for the benefit of both the author and the public?)

Answer (score 6):

Using a case statement in the set clause in your example isn't ideal for a number of reasons.

- There is no where clause to help the database execute the query efficiently
- The size of the query for large numbers of updates becomes excessive (consider updating 1000 rows like this)
- You are manually implementing a join - the database can almost certainly do this more efficiently than you.
- Debugging such a query is also difficult.

Instead, you should first **measure the performance** of the update one at a time approach to see if you actually need to make improvements.

If performance improvements are required, then I would suggest an approach where the updates are first bulk inserted into a temporary table. A suitable table would have the following columns:

```
wProductID, stockLocation, newStockLevel
```

The updates can be bulk inserted using the following MySQL syntax:

```
INSERT INTO temp_stock_updates
    (wProductID, stockLocation, newStockLevel)
VALUES
    (?,?,?), (?,?,?), (?,?,?), ...
```

And then a single update is run to update the main table. This query would look something like this:

```
UPDATE stockLevels s
    JOIN temp_stock_updates u USING (wProductID, stockLocation)
SET
    s.stockLevel = u.newStockLevel
```

Comment: OK, thanks for the advice. I am not 100% sure that the one at a time method is bad in this case, but I have certainly had issues with similar situations before. In this application it is unlikely we'd be dealing with more than 10-20 rows at a time, up to 3/4 locations, so potentially 80 loops... Could you expand on your suggested temporary table approach? I'm not sure what's going on there?

Comment: @JamieHartnoll, I've added some additional queries for the temporary table approach.

Comment: a'r I think you've probably got the best solution here, but the one I have accepted answer the question directly and I've been able to implement straight away. However, your solution does look better long term. I've never used temporary tables before and am not sure how to even go about making one, so am sticking with what I know for now! Thanks anyway!

Comment: @a'r One question. What do you mean by temporary table? Normal table which is created once, and then used just for updates purpose OR temporary table created on every update like that: www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-temporary-tables.htm

Comment: The official MySQL documentation has a better description of temporary tables. See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html